# Github Actions Docker build not working as expected

Tags: docker, dockerfile, github-actions

I have an nx workspace with 2 angular apps and I am building docker images with the below docker file giving as build argument the app name. Local everything is working as expected, but on my github actions first time when the argument is used it has the correct value, then is empty.

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:latest as build_env

ARG APP

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .


RUN npm install -g nx
RUN npm ci --legacy-peer-deps
RUN nx run $APP:build:production

FROM nginx:latest as run_env

ARG APP

COPY /nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY --from=build_env /app/dist/apps/$APP/ .

EXPOSE 80
```

Github action job

```
  build_admin_panel:
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Set up QEMU
        uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v2
      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2
      - name: Login to Docker Hub
        uses: docker/login-action@v2
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}
      - name: Build licenta orchestrator
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v4
        with:
          build_args: |
            APP=admin-panel
          push: true
          tags: user/image:latest
```

Github action log

```
#13 74.39 233 packages are looking for funding
#13 74.39   run `npm fund` for details
#13 74.39 
#13 74.39 1 high severity vulnerability
#13 74.39 
#13 74.39 To address all issues, run:
#13 74.39   npm audit fix
#13 74.39 
#13 74.39 Run `npm audit` for details.
#13 DONE 75.2s

#14 [build_env 6/6] RUN nx run $APP:build:production
#14 2.423 
#14 2.423 > nx run game-ui:build:production
#14 2.424 
# ....
#14 DONE 90.9s

#15 [run_env 4/4] COPY --from=build_env /app/dist/apps// .
#15 DONE 0.1s
```

With the APP build argument set to game-ui.
At step 14 the command is correct `nx run game-ui:build:production` .
At step 15 the APP argument is empty `COPY --from=build_env /app/dist/apps// .` should be `COPY --from=build_env /app/dist/apps/game-ui/ .`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot use ARGs in COPY commands. See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#using-arg-variables. Why bother with having a dynamic app directory anyway?